# Angular - Defining error type to HttpClient.post()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, rxjs

Is it possible to set the **type** of the return error to `HttpClient.post()`? I want to force anyone who is going to consume this service to use the properties that were defined in his error **interface**

Example:

```
// user.service.ts
    sendData(data: User) {
        return this.http
          .post<User>(`${BASE_ENDPOINT}/user`, data, {
            withCredentials: true
          })
      }

// user.component.ts
    this.user.sendData(null)
      .subscribe(
        (success: User) => console.log(success),
        (error: ResponseErrorUser) => console.log(error)
      );
```

Comment: So you want to change `ResponseErrorUser` to returned value from `HttpClient.post()` or what?

Comment: I want obligate that a colleague use `error: ResponseErrorUser` instead `error: any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Rxjs operators **catchError** and **throwError** to catch the error, map it into a custom object and throw this object.

```
import { catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
...
// user.service.ts
sendData(data: User) {
  return this.http
    .post<User>(`/api/v1/not-available`, data, {
      withCredentials: true
    })
    .pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        return throwError({
          statusCode: err.status,
          msg: err.message
        });
      })
    );
}

// user.component.ts
this.sendData(null).subscribe(
  (success: User) => console.log(success),
  (error: { statusCode: number; msg: string }) => console.error(error)
);
```

[image: Custom Error object]

For more information on custom error handling, I would recommend you to go through this [blog](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/).

Hope this helps. Cheers and happy coding!!!

Comment: I have already tried this. The problem is that you can use any in your error. I want that error just accept a specific type.

Comment: @Patrick As far as I know there is no way to force the type definition of error being thrown. All you can do is write documentation for your method using JSdocs specification as shown [here](https://jsdoc.app/tags-throws.html). If you fear that the client might not handle the error properly, console log the custom error object before throwing so that it will be there in the console while debugging.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort to help. I believe that I will opt for the @Shravan idea using JSdocs. Thanks.